# Alternative for sleep() in while loop?

Tags: c++, loops, sleep

I just wanted my main process to be alive until process is killed  .What can be used instead of sleep

Comment: Alternative for what purpose? Save power? What do you mean?

Comment: Are you using c, or c++? What _exactly_ are you trying to do? It might be better to describe exactly what you want and people can help. For example: "I'm trying to process something in another thread, and have the main thread wait until it's processed. Here is some code showing me using `sleep` and checking a `bool`, but it doesn't seem very good. I don't have c++11 so I can't use `std::conditional_variable`. How can I have my main loop wait while the other thread finishes processing?"

Comment: I am using c++ . Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I feel the down votes are not justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid "busy-waiting", eating up CPU power, as your code does, you want to use

```
pause();
```

to do the job.

From [`man pause`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html):

> **pause()** causes the calling process (or thread) to sleep until a
>          signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the
>          invocation of a signal-catching function.

---

It should be at least `int main(void)`, btw.

Comment: Or just `int main()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer alk ,i just wrote like that to give idea of what i am doing ,then i am not concerned about syntax but  only on solution